# How to change background color of calendar? <input type="datetime-local" >

Tags: html, css

What I tried:

HTML

```
<input type="datetime-local" >
```

[image: Change this bcak ground color from white to other color]

I want to change background color of calendar(displayed when we select calendar icon..currently white) to another color.

Is it possible to change the color?
can anyone help me this?

THANKYOU..!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any style options for the HTML5 Date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14946091/are-there-any-style-options-for-the-html5-date-picker)

Comment: try to explore link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18782689/how-to-change-the-background-image-on-particular-date-in-calendar-based-on-event

Comment: @Michel: This does not answer the question. Your link is about styling the input box, not the picker dialog.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwanMunawar You link is totally unrelated.

Answer (score 2):

The displayed control is dependant on the OS and the browser.
It is not an html element you can style.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local

You should look into using a custom date time pickers like:

- https://unpkg.com/flatpickr@1.6.5/index.html
- https://mymth.github.io/vanillajs-datepicker/#/